# Selecting button in second last td of first tr in table - Using jQuery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-selectors

I've been trying to write a selector in jQuery which selects a button with a class in the second last td of the first tr in  a table. This is what I've come up with so far:

```
$(':button.jtable-edit-command-button tr:first td:nth-last-of-type(2)').trigger('click');
```

But it doesn't work.

I've also tried this:

```
$(':button.jtable-edit-command-button:td:nth-last-of-type(2):tr:first').trigger('click');
```

But I get an error which says:

```
Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: td
```

Here's the [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/581Lem2f/1/) and [this W3 Schoosls tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp) is what I'm using for help. All help and suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use:

```js
$('.jtable-data-row:first-child td:nth-last-of-type(2) button').css('background', 'red');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tabs-Risks" class="tab ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" aria-labelledby="FourthTab" role="tabpanel" aria-expanded="true" aria-hidden="false" style="display: block;">
  <div id="RiskTableContainer" class="jTableContainer" style="width:100%;">
    <div class="jtable-main-container">
      <div class="jtable-busy-panel-background jtable-busy-panel-background-invisible" style="display: none; width: 1432px; height: 835px;"></div>
      <div class="jtable-busy-message" style="display: none;"></div>
      <div class="jtable-title">
        <div class="jtable-title-text">Risks</div>
      </div>
      <table class="jtable">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th class="jtable-column-header jtable-column-header-sortable jtable-column-header-sorted-asc" style="width: 3.91146589259797%;">
              <div class="jtable-column-header-container"><span class="jtable-column-header-text">WBS</span>

              </div>
            </th>
            <th class="jtable-column-header jtable-column-header-sortable" style="display: table-cell; width: 6.25834542815675%;">
              <div class="jtable-column-header-container"> <span class="jtable-column-header-text">Task Name</span>

                <div class="jtable-column-resize-handler"></div>
              </div>
            </th>
            <th class="jtable-column-header jtable-column-header-sortable" style="width: 6.47169811320755%;">
              <div class="jtable-column-header-container"> <span class="jtable-column-header-text">Risk Event</span>

                <div class="jtable-column-resize-handler"></div>
              </div>
            </th>
            <th class="jtable-column-header jtable-column-header-sortable" style="width: 5.40493468795356%;">
              <div class="jtable-column-header-container"><span class="jtable-column-header-text">Date of Concern</span>

              </div>
            </th>
            <th class="jtable-column-header jtable-column-header-sortable" style="width: 8.88969521044993%;">
              <div class="jtable-column-header-container"> <span class="jtable-column-header-text">Impact</span>

                <div class="jtable-column-resize-handler"></div>
              </div>
            </th>
            <th class="jtable-column-header jtable-column-header-sortable" style="width: 6.04499274310595%;">
              <div class="jtable-column-header-container"><span class="jtable-column-header-text">Date Identified</span>

              </div>
            </th>
            <th class="jtable-column-header jtable-column-header-sortable" style="width: 4.26705370101597%;">
              <div class="jtable-column-header-container"> <span class="jtable-column-header-text">Days Open</span>

                <div class="jtable-column-resize-handler"></div>
              </div>
            </th>
            <th class="jtable-column-header jtable-column-header-sortable" style="display: none;">
              <div class="jtable-column-header-container"> <span class="jtable-column-header-text">Date Closed</span>

                <div class="jtable-column-resize-handler"></div>
              </div>
            </th>
            <th class="jtable-column-header jtable-column-header-sortable" style="display: none;">
              <div class="jtable-column-header-container"> <span class="jtable-column-header-text">Type</span>

                <div class="jtable-column-resize-handler"></div>
              </div>
            </th>
            <th class="jtable-column-header jtable-column-header-sortable" style="display: none;">
              <div class="jtable-column-header-container"> <span class="jtable-column-header-text">Mitigation Cost</span>

                <div class="jtable-column-resize-handler"></div>
              </div>
            </th>
            <th class="jtable-column-header jtable-column-header-sortable" style="width: 6.54281567489115%;">
              <div class="jtable-column-header-container"><span class="jtable-column-header-text">Probability</span>

              </div>
            </th>
            <th class="jtable-column-header jtable-column-header-sortable" style="width: 4.83599419448476%;">
              <div class="jtable-column-header-container"> <span class="jtable-column-header-text">Impact Effect</span>

                <div class="jtable-column-resize-handler"></div>
              </div>
            </th>
            <th class="jtable-column-header jtable-column-header-sortable" style="width: 4.83599419448476%;">
              <div class="jtable-column-header-container"> <span class="jtable-column-header-text">Cost Impact</span>

                <div class="jtable-column-resize-handler"></div>
              </div>
            </th>
            <th class="jtable-column-header jtable-column-header-sortable" style="width: 4.97822931785196%;">
              <div class="jtable-column-header-container"><span class="jtable-column-header-text">Overall Impact</span>

              </div>
            </th>
            <th class="jtable-column-header jtable-column-header-sortable" style="width: 5.90275761973875%;">
              <div class="jtable-column-header-container"> <span class="jtable-column-header-text">Expected Cost</span>

                <div class="jtable-column-resize-handler"></div>
              </div>
            </th>
            <th class="jtable-column-header jtable-column-header-sortable" style="width: 14.2235123367199%;">
              <div class="jtable-column-header-container"> <span class="jtable-column-header-text">Impact Discussion</span>

                <div class="jtable-column-resize-handler"></div>
              </div>
            </th>
            <th class="jtable-column-header jtable-column-header-sortable" style="width: 5.12046444121916%;">
              <div class="jtable-column-header-container"><span class="jtable-column-header-text">Priority Effect</span>

              </div>
            </th>
            <th class="jtable-column-header jtable-column-header-sortable" style="width: 5.12046444121916%;">
              <div class="jtable-column-header-container"><span class="jtable-column-header-text">Priority ($)</span>

              </div>
            </th>
            <th class="jtable-column-header jtable-column-header-sortable" style="width: 5.19158200290276%;">
              <div class="jtable-column-header-container"><span class="jtable-column-header-text">Severe?</span>

              </div>
            </th>
            <th class="jtable-command-column-header" style="width: 1%;"></th>
            <th class="jtable-command-column-header" style="width: 1%;"></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr class="jtable-data-row" data-record-key="267">
            <td>1.0</td>
            <td>Obtain building permits</td>
            <td><a href="http://shhasan.ddns.net/risk/view/267">get building permit earlier</a>

            </td>
            <td>2014-03-18</td>
            <td>start dry wall job earlier then expected</td>
            <td>2014-01-21</td>
            <td>269</td>
            <td style="display: none;">2014-10-17</td>
            <td style="display: none;">Opportunity</td>
            <td style="display: none;"></td>
            <td>0%</td>
            <td>70</td>
            <td>$3000</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>$0</td>
            <td>This will only effect dry wallers</td>
            <td>10</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>No</td>
            <td class="jtable-command-column">
              <button title="Edit Risk" class="jtable-command-button jtable-edit-command-button"><span>Edit Risk</span>

              </button>
            </td>
            <td class="jtable-command-column">
              <button title="Delete" class="jtable-command-button jtable-delete-command-button"><span>Delete</span>

              </button>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="jtable-data-row jtable-row-even" data-record-key="650">
            <td>14.3.1</td>
            <td>Plumbing</td>
            <td><a href="http://shhasan.ddns.net/risk/view/650">Leaks</a>

            </td>
            <td>2014-10-05</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>2014-09-26</td>
            <td>26</td>
            <td style="display: none;">2014-10-22</td>
            <td style="display: none;">Threat</td>
            <td style="display: none;"></td>
            <td>0%</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>$1002</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>$0</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>10</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>No</td>
            <td class="jtable-command-column">
              <button title="Edit Risk" class="jtable-command-button jtable-edit-command-button"><span>Edit Risk</span>

              </button>
            </td>
            <td class="jtable-command-column">
              <button title="Delete" class="jtable-command-button jtable-delete-command-button"><span>Delete</span>

              </button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
```

Reference: [MDN - :first-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child), [MDN - :nth-last-of-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-last-of-type)

Comment: Wow, I never knew that `nth-last-child` existed.

Comment: An important note is that nth-last-child considers ALL the children, not just the ones that match the element type. For example, if the second to last element in the row was not a td, it would still be selected.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response. Your suggestion works. Is there a way I could select only the button which is in the `div` with `id="tabs-Risks"` ?

Comment: Sure you could add `#tabs-Risks` in front of selector.

Comment: Found it: `$('#tabs-Risks .jtable-data-row:first-child td:nth-last-of-type(2) button').trigger('click');`

Answer (score 4):

Alternative you can:

```js
$('#tabs-Risks .jtable tr:eq(1) td:nth-last-child(2) button').css('color', 'red');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tabs-Risks" class="tab ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" aria-labelledby="FourthTab" role="tabpanel" aria-expanded="true" aria-hidden="false" style="display: block;">
  <div id="RiskTableContainer" class="jTableContainer" style="width:100%;">
    <div class="jtable-main-container">
      <div class="jtable-busy-panel-background jtable-busy-panel-background-invisible" style="display: none; width: 1432px; height: 835px;"></div>
      <div class="jtable-busy-message" style="display: none;"></div>
      <div class="jtable-title">
        <div class="jtable-title-text">Risks</div>
      </div>
      <table class="jtable">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th class="jtable-column-header jtable-column-header-sortable jtable-column-header-sorted-asc" style="width: 3.91146589259797%;">
              <div class="jtable-column-header-container"><span class="jtable-column-header-text">WBS</span>

              </div>
            </th>
            <th class="jtable-column-header jtable-column-header-sortable" style="display: table-cell; width: 6.25834542815675%;">
              <div class="jtable-column-header-container"> <span class="jtable-column-header-text">Task Name</span>

                <div class="jtable-column-resize-handler"></div>
              </div>
            </th>
            <th class="jtable-column-header jtable-column-header-sortable" style="width: 6.47169811320755%;">
              <div class="jtable-column-header-container"> <span class="jtable-column-header-text">Risk Event</span>

                <div class="jtable-column-resize-handler"></div>
              </div>
            </th>
            <th class="jtable-column-header jtable-column-header-sortable" style="width: 5.40493468795356%;">
              <div class="jtable-column-header-container"><span class="jtable-column-header-text">Date of Concern</span>

              </div>
            </th>
            <th class="jtable-column-header jtable-column-header-sortable" style="width: 8.88969521044993%;">
              <div class="jtable-column-header-container"> <span class="jtable-column-header-text">Impact</span>

                <div class="jtable-column-resize-handler"></div>
              </div>
            </th>
            <th class="jtable-column-header jtable-column-header-sortable" style="width: 6.04499274310595%;">
              <div class="jtable-column-header-container"><span class="jtable-column-header-text">Date Identified</span>

              </div>
            </th>
            <th class="jtable-column-header jtable-column-header-sortable" style="width: 4.26705370101597%;">
              <div class="jtable-column-header-container"> <span class="jtable-column-header-text">Days Open</span>

                <div class="jtable-column-resize-handler"></div>
              </div>
            </th>
            <th class="jtable-column-header jtable-column-header-sortable" style="display: none;">
              <div class="jtable-column-header-container"> <span class="jtable-column-header-text">Date Closed</span>

                <div class="jtable-column-resize-handler"></div>
              </div>
            </th>
            <th class="jtable-column-header jtable-column-header-sortable" style="display: none;">
              <div class="jtable-column-header-container"> <span class="jtable-column-header-text">Type</span>

                <div class="jtable-column-resize-handler"></div>
              </div>
            </th>
            <th class="jtable-column-header jtable-column-header-sortable" style="display: none;">
              <div class="jtable-column-header-container"> <span class="jtable-column-header-text">Mitigation Cost</span>

                <div class="jtable-column-resize-handler"></div>
              </div>
            </th>
            <th class="jtable-column-header jtable-column-header-sortable" style="width: 6.54281567489115%;">
              <div class="jtable-column-header-container"><span class="jtable-column-header-text">Probability</span>

              </div>
            </th>
            <th class="jtable-column-header jtable-column-header-sortable" style="width: 4.83599419448476%;">
              <div class="jtable-column-header-container"> <span class="jtable-column-header-text">Impact Effect</span>

                <div class="jtable-column-resize-handler"></div>
              </div>
            </th>
            <th class="jtable-column-header jtable-column-header-sortable" style="width: 4.83599419448476%;">
              <div class="jtable-column-header-container"> <span class="jtable-column-header-text">Cost Impact</span>

                <div class="jtable-column-resize-handler"></div>
              </div>
            </th>
            <th class="jtable-column-header jtable-column-header-sortable" style="width: 4.97822931785196%;">
              <div class="jtable-column-header-container"><span class="jtable-column-header-text">Overall Impact</span>

              </div>
            </th>
            <th class="jtable-column-header jtable-column-header-sortable" style="width: 5.90275761973875%;">
              <div class="jtable-column-header-container"> <span class="jtable-column-header-text">Expected Cost</span>

                <div class="jtable-column-resize-handler"></div>
              </div>
            </th>
            <th class="jtable-column-header jtable-column-header-sortable" style="width: 14.2235123367199%;">
              <div class="jtable-column-header-container"> <span class="jtable-column-header-text">Impact Discussion</span>

                <div class="jtable-column-resize-handler"></div>
              </div>
            </th>
            <th class="jtable-column-header jtable-column-header-sortable" style="width: 5.12046444121916%;">
              <div class="jtable-column-header-container"><span class="jtable-column-header-text">Priority Effect</span>

              </div>
            </th>
            <th class="jtable-column-header jtable-column-header-sortable" style="width: 5.12046444121916%;">
              <div class="jtable-column-header-container"><span class="jtable-column-header-text">Priority ($)</span>

              </div>
            </th>
            <th class="jtable-column-header jtable-column-header-sortable" style="width: 5.19158200290276%;">
              <div class="jtable-column-header-container"><span class="jtable-column-header-text">Severe?</span>

              </div>
            </th>
            <th class="jtable-command-column-header" style="width: 1%;"></th>
            <th class="jtable-command-column-header" style="width: 1%;"></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr class="jtable-data-row" data-record-key="267">
            <td>1.0</td>
            <td>Obtain building permits</td>
            <td><a href="http://shhasan.ddns.net/risk/view/267">get building permit earlier</a>

            </td>
            <td>2014-03-18</td>
            <td>start dry wall job earlier then expected</td>
            <td>2014-01-21</td>
            <td>269</td>
            <td style="display: none;">2014-10-17</td>
            <td style="display: none;">Opportunity</td>
            <td style="display: none;"></td>
            <td>0%</td>
            <td>70</td>
            <td>$3000</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>$0</td>
            <td>This will only effect dry wallers</td>
            <td>10</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>No</td>
            <td class="jtable-command-column">
              <button title="Edit Risk" class="jtable-command-button jtable-edit-command-button"><span>Edit Risk</span>

              </button>
            </td>
            <td class="jtable-command-column">
              <button title="Delete" class="jtable-command-button jtable-delete-command-button"><span>Delete</span>

              </button>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="jtable-data-row jtable-row-even" data-record-key="650">
            <td>14.3.1</td>
            <td>Plumbing</td>
            <td><a href="http://shhasan.ddns.net/risk/view/650">Leaks</a>

            </td>
            <td>2014-10-05</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>2014-09-26</td>
            <td>26</td>
            <td style="display: none;">2014-10-22</td>
            <td style="display: none;">Threat</td>
            <td style="display: none;"></td>
            <td>0%</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>$1002</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>$0</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>10</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>No</td>
            <td class="jtable-command-column">
              <button title="Edit Risk" class="jtable-command-button jtable-edit-command-button"><span>Edit Risk</span>

              </button>
            </td>
            <td class="jtable-command-column">
              <button title="Delete" class="jtable-command-button jtable-delete-command-button"><span>Delete</span>

              </button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
```

Of course in your example you use `.trigger()` instead of `.css()`.

**References:**

[:eq()](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)

[:nth-last-child()](https://api.jquery.com/nth-last-child-selector/)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. It works as well.Is there a way I could select only the button which is in the `div` with `id="tabs-Risks"` ?

Comment: Found it: `$('#tabs-Risks .jtable-data-row:first-child td:nth-last-of-type(2) button').trigger('click');`

Comment: Both solutions work perfectly. I selected emmanuel's answer because he answered first.